# Trying to pickup mp4 & srt files in a dir and combine them using one script

Tags: windows, powershell, ffmpeg

Using this code works fine:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v subtitles=subtitle.srt -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

Trying to batch the operation gives errors:

```
ls | Where { $_.Extension -eq ".mp4" } | ForEach {

.\ffmpeg.exe -i $_.Name -filter:v subtitles=$_.Name.Replace(".mp4", ".srt") -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast $_.Name.Replace(".mp4", "WithSubs.mp4") 

}
```

Error:

> Output file #1 does not contain any stream
> an empty file is made called ".mp4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by declaring the subtitles file name and the output name:

```
$NewName = $_.Name.Replace(".mp4", "WithSubs.mp4");
$SubsName = $_.Name.Replace(".mp4", ".srt");
write-output $NewName;
write-output $SubsName;
.\ffmpeg.exe -i $_.Name -filter:v subtitles=$SubsName -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast $NewName
```

Comment: If this solved the issue you might want to accept your own answer (you can always accept another one in the future if needed)